# Why we need Wildcard Capture?

Tags: java, generics

In the official tutorials [#Wildcard Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html) and [Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) and its easy-understanding demos as:

```
public class WildcardFixed {

    void foo(List<?> i) {
        fooHelper(i);
    }
    private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l) {
        l.set(0, l.get(0));
    }
}
```

I've also read some posts in StackOverflow discussing Wildcard Capture but when I try to use it as

```
public static <T> void addToSet(Set<T> s, T t) {
// I was hoping the type inference will infer the T to String
}

private static <T> Set<T> setWrapper(Set<T> theSet) {
    return theSet;
}

public static void testUnboundedWildcard() {
    Set<?> unknownSet = new HashSet<String>();

    // ------> here lies the compile error <-------
    HelloWorld.<String>addToSet(setWrapper(unknownSet), "abc");
}
```

The compile error shows

```
Error:(52, 47) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: java.lang.String
    equality constraints(s): java.lang.String,capture#1 of ?
```

I thought I can **capture** the wildcard and do things as [`generic method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) but I was completely wrong.

#### My Confusion

1. why my code using *Wildcard Capture* cannot work?
2. if it just cannot work then why **exactly** we need it? any specific scenarios can be found?

Comment: A `HashSet<Void>` would also be a `Set<?>`. The compiler doesn't know that `unknownSet` is "really" a `HashSet<String>`

Comment: @AndyTurner Isn't `wildcard capture` **capture** the **wildcard** and render it as `T` and so when I passing in a string, it should work?

Comment: no. The wildcard type is *some* type, not any specific type.

Comment: @AndyTurner then the `wildcard capture` is only working for the case shown in `FooHelper`? Just for adding something being out from itself? Sorry, I cannot think of any usage...

Answer (score 2):

> why exactly we need it? any specific scenarios can be found?

You can use it when you only need to work with the base type and really don't care about the generic type.

For example, you could have a method

```
boolean hasTooManyElements(Collection<?> data){
    return data.size() > 100;
}
```

Without a wildcard you would have to  (without good reason) limit this method to work only on Collections of specific types.

Note that a wildcard can still be bounded:

```
boolean hasEmptyText(Collection<? extends CharSequence> data) {
   return data.exists(x -> x.isEmpty()); 
   // you can call `isEmpty` because of the bounded wildcard
}
```

You could also express this by making your method generic (but there is not much point if you are not going to use the type `T` anywhere).

```
<T> boolean hasTooManyElements(Collection<T> data);
```

You want to have the `<T>` in cases like this:

```
// limit the return type
<T> T getRandomElement(Collection<T> data);
// or, more flexible
<T> T getRandomElement(Collection<? extends T> data);

// make sure the two inputs have the same generic type
<T> boolean areEqual(Collection<T> one, Collection<T> two);
```

Comment: An implicit point in your answer is that wildcard types are useful for *method parameters*. If you are using them elsewhere, there is likely a design problem with the API you are using. There is a lengthy item about wildcards in *Effective Java*, called something like "use wildcards to increase the flexibility of your APIs".

Comment: @AndyTurner Why wouldn't you have them on local variables or fields? Or what else do you have in mind?

Comment: can you show an example where it *would* be useful? Note that all of your examples are parameters.

Comment: `Set<?> unknownSet = new HashSet<String>();` of course is not useful. If you know the type, just put it there. Purposefully "forgetting" the type should not be necessary anywhere I think.

Comment: You could have a "metric recorder" that every X seconds logs the size of a buffer or queue. An object instance of that could have a `Collection<?> target` field.

Comment: I think for return types, it only makes sense in extreme edge-cases, like `Class::forName(String classname)` which returns a `Class<?>`.

Comment: for the "metric recorder" case you could have an `IntSupplier` instead. And that is a better abstraction if all you want to record is the size.

Comment: "extreme edge cases" right: wildcards should rarely be used like this. Certainly if you are trying to understand their main purpose, such cases do not really need to be discussed, other than in passing, and suitably disclaimed as atypical.

Comment: @Thilo Sorry to reply this late, but my concern is merely about why we need `wildcard  capture` instead of `unbounded wildcard` which I kind of understand as your answer mentioned since it's already fully discussed in the official tutorials which I already enclosed.